# Selenium webdriver : How to assert if a radiobox / checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xamarin.android

i'm using Selenium webdriver with **javascript & node.js**

In some step in my test, i have to test (assert) *if a specific radiobox is already checked*.

i wanna test if it s trully checked , then , my test is would be successful.

Actually i have tried to do that:

```
  var radioInput = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('//*[@id="radio1'));
  radioInput.isSelected().then(function() {
    done();
  });
```

i don't know but that doesn't seem working.

**Suggestions?**

Comment: can you share your html code for the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solve it this way:

```
var element = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('//*[@id="radioID"]'));

element.getAttribute("checked").then(function(value) {
  assert.equal(value, 'true');
  //traitement
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try instead `var radioInput = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('//*[@id="radio1'));`
use `driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(driver.findElement(By.` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Store the output from the isSelected method and have a condition statement such as if/else accordingly,

```
            var radioInput = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('//*[@id="radio1'));
            var state = radioInput.isSelected();
            if(state)
            {
                //THINGS TO DO IF RADIO IS ON
            }
            else
            {
                //THINGS TO DO IF RADIO IS OFF
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP's code adjusted, using promises:

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('//*[@id="radio1'))
  .then((radioInput) => radioInput.isSelected())
  .then((selected) => {
    if (selected) {
      done();
    }
  });
```